# How to trace complete URL after parameters as object are added to flex httpservice?

Tags: actionscript-3, url, flex3, parameter-passing, httpservice

I want to trace how URL looks when it is sent like in following example when using params:

```
http.url="func.php";
var params:Object = { abc: "123", def: "456" };
http.send(params);

trace(http.url);  // traces only "func.php"
trace("params ",params);  // traces params  [object Object]
```

I want to get this traced:

```
func.php?abc=123&def=456
```

How to trace complete URL with added parameters that is sent?

Also, I used Charles debug proxy, but could not get which URL was sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your issue is just about tracing the content of an object, you can write something like that

```
for(var key:String in params)
{
  trace(key, params[key]);
}
```